# Jquery data table column filter header responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have tried Bootstrap jQuery data table column filter in header

http://jsfiddle.net/80umxrxe/122/

thead 2nd row column filter design was not working in responsive window, i want to hide like in the thead 1st row

thead 1st row was title
thead 2nd row was filters

My code is below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">     
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#example .filters td').each( function () {
                var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
            } );

            // DataTable
                var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                    responsive: true
                });

            // Apply the search
            table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
                $( 'input', $('.filters td')[colIdx] ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    table
                        .column( colIdx )
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                } );
            } );
        } );

        </script>
        <style>
        .filters input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead class="filters">
            <tr>
                <td>First name</td>
                <td>Last name</td>
                <td>Position</td>
                <td>Office</td>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Start date</td>
                <td>Salary</td>
                <td>Extn.</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>6224</td>
                <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
                <td>4804</td>
                <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
                <td>9608</td>
                <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

1st row design working fine in responsive
2nd row design not working want to hide the column filter like in the 1st row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex headers are not supported with Responsive plug-in 2.0 and 2.1, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753316/3549014) for more details.

The workaround could be to rollback to version 1.0 until author releases a fix.

Your HTML markup is incorrect, you should use single `thead` with `tr` for each row and `th` for each column.

See [corrected example](http://jsfiddle.net/80umxrxe/125/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Filter Header working with Responsive [more details here](https://codepen.io/rajneesh-vishwakarma/pen/NWaZxqo)

by creating a function

```
function hideSearchInputs(columns) {
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  if (columns[i]) {
    $(".filters th:eq(" + i + ")").show();
  } else {
    $(".filters th:eq(" + i + ")").hide();
  }
}
```

}

see [this link](https://codepen.io/rajneesh-vishwakarma/pen/NWaZxqo) for more details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).